# Is it possible to create a Rmd file template for the blogdown "new post" addin?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I find myself using a lot of the same R code in my Rmd posts and currently have a template file from where I copy paste this common R code into new posts. However, now I wonder if it's possible to modify the Rmd post template to include these lines of common R code and some reminders to myself on how to do a few things. It would be nice if this worked with the blogdown addin "new post" in RStudio.

I searched here, the blogdown book and the blogdown repo and didn't see information on how to do this. The [closest](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/default-template.html) is for modifying the html template, not the Rmd template.

Here's an example Rmd file that I would like to use as my Rmd post [template](https://gist.github.com/lcolladotor/eafaae5de96d84440acee4fc9393ffcc)

PS: Blogged about this [here](http://lcolladotor.github.io/2018/02/17/r-markdown-blog-template/%20and%20finally%20at%20http://lcolladotor.github.io/2018/03/08/blogdown-archetype-template/).

Comment: You could modify the appropriate file inside `archetypes` folder (say `post.md`) to include all the code you want. Then when you do `hugo new post/new.md` all that code would be included. However, I can't get it to work with `blogdown` addin or with `blogdown::new_content`. I could be wrong but `blogdown` does not seem to care about the `archetypes`

Comment: Hi @d.b, thanks for your comment! Yihui's answer and your comment lead me to write https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/173#issuecomment-367888459. Maybe you can contribute more information for Yihui to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a template using the file `/archetypes/default.md`. Its content will be used for your new posts.

Alternatively, you can use the `kind` argument of `blogdown::new_post()` (or `blogdown::new_content()`), which should be the name of the "archetype" (see [Hugo's documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/archetypes/)).

---

**Update**: there was [a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/261) in `blogdown::new_content()`, which [has been fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/pull/263) by the OP. For now, `devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')` should work.

Comment: This worked a treat, but I had to restart the R environment (I think that was the problem..) for it to kick in..